# Is it safe to access asp.net Mvc3 session variables through static properties of a static object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session, static

this issue explain the question here 
[Is it safe to access asp.net session variables through static properties of a static object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804256/is-it-safe-to-access-asp-net-session-variables-through-static-properties-of-a-st#_=_)
but my example may be more complicated，is it safe ?

```
public static class SessionManager
{
    public static tbuser User
    {
        get
        {
             var user = HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] as tbuser
             user.money = RetriveFromDb(user.name)
             HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] = user;
             return user;
        }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if your `HttpContext.Current.Session["User"]` is null? In that case, `user.money = RetriveFromD(user.name)` will throw an `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @DoanCuong,thanks for u advice. what i want to know is it thread safe ?.tow or more theads will entry and execute the get method, will the var user changed by other thread?  thank you

Comment: Base on my knowledge, your implementation is safe. Because `var user = HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] as tbuser;` is encapsulated inside `get` block, therefore each attempt to access your class will be provided a corresponding instance of `HttpContext.Current.Session["User"]` for that session.